# Grouping XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i am a little bit stuck with grouping. I have the following XML-Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <isif_data>
        <date>29.05.
            <event-date>
                <type>type1</type>
                <Time Timesort="1845">18.45</Time>
                <title>event1</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abc</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type1</type>
                <Time Timesort="0900">9</Time>
                <title>event2</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abd</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type2</type>
                <Time Timesort="1930">19.30</Time>
                <title>event3</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abe</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type2</type>
                <Time Timesort="1900">19</Time>
                <title>event4</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abf</place>
            </event-date>
        </date>
        <date>30.05.
            <event-date>
                <type>type1</type>
                <Time Timesort="1845">18.45</Time>
                <title>event5</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abg</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type2</type>
                <Time Timesort="0900">9</Time>
                <title>event6</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abh</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type1        </type>
                <Time Timesort="1500">15</Time>
                <title>event7</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abi</place>
            </event-date>
            <event-date>
                <type>type2</type>
                <Time Timesort="1700">17</Time>
                <title>event8</title>
                <cell/>
                <place>abj</place>
            </event-date>
        </date>
    </isif_data>
```

Now i need the resulting XML to look something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <isif_data>
     <date>29.05.</date>
     <type>type1</type>
     <Time>9</Time>
     <title>event2</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abd</place>
     <Time>18.45</Time>
     <title>event1</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abc</place>
     <type>type2</type>
     <Time>19</Time>
     <title>event4</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abf</place>
     <Time>19.30</Time>
     <title>event3</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abe</place>
     <date>30.05.</date>
     <type>type1</type>
     <Time>15</Time>
     <title>event7</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abi</place>
     <Time>18.45</Time>
     <title>event5</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abg</place>
     <type>type2</type>
     <Time>9</Time>
     <title>event6</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abh</place>
     <Time>17</Time>
     <title>event8</title>
     <cell/>
     <place>abj</place>
    </isif_data>
```

I tried it with the Muenchian Method but i never got it working like i want. Anybody here, who has an idea how to get it working? I need to use xsl version 1.0. If you need more infos just tell me. Thanks in advance :-)

Edit: I tried the following XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="type" match="event-date" use="type" />
     <xsl:template match="isif_data">
      <xsl:element name="isif_data">
       <xsl:for-each select="date">
        <xsl:element name="date"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="cell"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="event-date[count(. | key('type', type)[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="time/@Timesort" />
           <xsl:call-template name="type" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('type', type)">
             <xsl:call-template name="time" />
             <xsl:call-template name="title" />
             <xsl:call-template name="place" />
            </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need templates i can provide them too. I'm not really sure if it they are needed.

Comment: Updated my Original Post.

Comment: I strongly recommend you get rid of the mixed-content elements. Either your nodes contain text, or they contain child elements. Not both. You'll put yourself into trouble needlessly with mixed content.

Comment: Have you read: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html ?

Comment: Alright, i updated my original port. Thanks @michael.hor257k for the info. Now the grouping works. But not quite right. Is there a possibility to make a group for each date-tag from the original code?

Comment: And thank you @Tomalak. My fault for posting the wrong result. I actually made my xsl to transform the way you suggested. I have an attribute in the date-tag wich provides me with the needed text. So the text in the node is quite needless. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to make a group for each date-tag from the
>   original code?

This:

```
<xsl:key name="type" match="event-date" use="type" />
```

will group all event-dates by type, regardless of date. Since you want to group the events by type **within each date**, you need to use both date and type in the key:

```
<xsl:key name="type" match="event-date" use="concat (../., '|', type)" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't know why i didn't see this before. You're the best.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the types with or without the spaces should be grouped in one, you indeed need to do the keying because of the normalizing of spaces that needs to take place. It will then look something like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="types" match="event-date"
      use="concat(normalize-space(../text()), normalize-space(type))"/>
   <xsl:template match="event-date">
     <xsl:variable name="thisType" select="normalize-space(type)"/>
     <xsl:variable name="thisSet"
        select="key('types', concat(normalize-space(../text()), $thisType))"/>
     <xsl:if test="count(. | $thisSet[1]) = 1">
       <type><xsl:value-of select="$thisType"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="$thisSet">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
       </type>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="type"/>
   <xsl:template match="node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Without the spaces, etc. you don't need the whole keying stuff. Then it would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template
    match="event-date[not(type = preceding-sibling::*/type)]">
    <type><xsl:value-of select="type"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[type=current()/type]/node()"/>
    </type>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="event-date | type"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Muenchian grouping is not about spaces, etc. - it's about performance. Your alternative using a predicate is "very inefficient" (quoting from the article mentioned above).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this question concerned a performance issue. I would say that in this case performance largely depends on the number of dates and events within the date. I am not sure that Muenchian grouping will always lead to a better performance here.